# Understanding the proof of the divergence of the Harmonic Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

In my textbook, they show their own proof that the Harmonic Series diverges, which I don't understand.

The harmonic series is defined as $s_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$. They have proved that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $s_{2^n} \gt 1 + n/2$. And because it is monotonically increasing, it must be diverging to $\infty$ (since they claim it is not bounded above). But how can you deduce from this that it is not bounded above?

If a series is not bounded above, then for *all* $M \in \mathbb R$, there is an $N \in \mathbb R$ such that $s_n \gt M$ for all $n \gt N$. But the textbook hasn't picked an arbitrary real number. Instead, they chose $1 + n/2$ instead of, say, $n$.

Can someone please explain  this? Thanks.

Comment: $1+n/2$ is not bounded above. And $s_{2^n}$ is even larger ...

Comment: Btw, $s_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ makes no sense, it should be $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the given inequality, but use it the other way round. Choose some $M\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $n=2(M-1)$. Then
$$s_{2^n} > 1 + \frac{n}{2} = M.$$
Another way of looking at this is to note that clearly $1+\frac{n}{2}$ is not bounded above, so given some $M$, simply choose $n$ such that $1+\frac{n}{2}>M$; then $s_{2^n}>M$.